# "How did you get here?" after the intro mission and no further missions available

Tags: deadbolt

I was replaying Deadbolt from the very beginning by pressing New Game in the main menu and after completing the introduction mission to my satisfaction, I entered the apartment with cardboard boxes and there was no Candle Guy to welcome me, and sitting in the chair got me the text "How did you get here?"

Is this a bug or did I wander into some secret?

The room before doing anything:

[image]

The text after sitting in the chair:

[image]

The absence of further missions:

[image]

---

For comparison, normal development of events after finishing the intro mission:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It happens if you complete the introductory mission with only melee weapons (Meaning knife only). Dont know if you can get it someway else but i can cause the lock of progression consistently using only knife.